# number of lines is equal to number of names

Tags: java, file-handling

if anyone can help me please in java programme  , I have file called "input.txt" which contains text like

```
Agent1 R F 2 0
Agent2 R B 4 5
Agent4 C E 2 2
Agent3 R F 3 11
```

I want to save all the lines in different variable and do work on them.
say here I want to save the first line into string which I will call line1, second line I will save in string called  line2 third line I will save on string called line3 and so on.

is their any way to do that. my txt file can have any number of line and I want to save those lines as strings do work on them.

simply I need something like a loop which will keep on changing the name of variable . but i have no idea how to do it.

here is my code till now but instead of output i want to save lines as string of any data type

any help really appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the work/code you have done until now?

Comment: "I want to save all the lines in different variable" - it sounds like you should really use a `List`, e.g. `ArrayList`.

Comment: @JonSkeet OHMYGOD!!! Look who it is!!

Comment: Thanks for  the solution guys actually i am just a beginner in java so not familiar with difficult functions.

Comment: my requirement for this code is to have a input form the file  take the text line by line  and sort the lines in increasing order  according to  the second last element of each line and save it to new file called myout.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static Map<String, String> loadFile(Reader reader)
        throws IllegalArgumentException{
    Map<String, String> mapList = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    if(reader == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Reader not valid");
    }
    String line;
    innerReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    int countLine = 0;
    try
    {
    while((line = innerReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line == null || line.trim().isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Line Empty");
        mapList.put("line"+String.valueOf(countLine), line);
        countLine++;
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return mapList;
}
```

In main add this to try your code.

```
Map<String, String> mapList = new TreeMap<String, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    try {
        mapList = loadFile(new FileReader("YourFile.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Map.Entry entry : mapList.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
```

}

Ann this is output.

> line0, Agent1 R F 2 0
>
> line1, Agent2 R B 4 5
>
> line2, Agent4 C E 2 2
>
> line3, Agent3 R F 3 11

For print out in file add this:

```
private static PrintWriter innerWriter;
public static void printMap(Map<String, String> myMap, Writer writer)
            throws IOException {
        if(writer == null)
        {
            throw new IOException("Cannot open file");
        }
        innerWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
        for (Map.Entry entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
            innerWriter.write(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + "\n");

         //OR THIS FOR ONLY VALUES
         // innerWriter.write(entry.getValue() + "\n");

        }
        innerWriter.close();
    }
```

and this on main

```
try {
        printMap(mapList, new FileWriter("FileOutput.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i have got the whole value in names and i can acess each line using names.get(0) for first line name.get(1) for second line but still i have to save it somewhere ,my motive is to rearrange the line according to the second last element of each line. i want actually like this to be saved in the output.txt file                                                                                                                  Agent1 R F 2 0 (NEWLINE i dont know how to give new line in comment i press enter i port comment  )
Agent4 C E 2 2(NEWLINE)
Agent3 R F 3 11(NEWLINE )
Agent2 R  B 4 5(NEWLINE)

Comment: thanks for editing mate but i think it will put the same input file to the output file but is it possible to have the output file lines sorted according to the second last element of each line and out put the sorted lines in the output file.

Comment: you should create the object class that want to save and then order, from what you wrote above you are not understood very well

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create variables at the fly, like you mentioned just by changing the name. You can use `List` for storing the data from file and process it later.

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  names.add(line);
}
// Now all the lines from the file are stored in the list.
// You can do the processing you need to do.
```

Convert the `List` of `Strings` into `String` array and use the `Arrays.sort` method for sorting the array. We will provide the custom `Comparator` to sort the array as per our needs.

```
String nameArray[] = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
Arrays.sort(nameArray, new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    String array1[] = o1.split(" ");
    String array2[] = o2.split(" ");
    return array1[3].compareTo(array2[3]);
  }
});
```

The assumption here is lines will always contain the five elements and we are sorting by fourth position number in the line.

---

**output:**

```
Agent1 R F 2 0
Agent4 C E 2 2
Agent3 R F 3 11
Agent2 R B 4 5
```

Comment: bro , i have got the whole value in names and i can acess each line using names.get(0) for first line name.get(1) for second line but still i have to save it somewhere ,my motive is to rearrange the line according to the second last element of each line.

Comment: i want actually like this to be saved in the output.txt file                                                                                                                  Agent1 R F 2 0 (NEWLINE i dont know how to give new line in comment i press enter i port comment  )
Agent4 C E 2 2(NEWLINE)
Agent3 R F 3 11(NEWLINE )
Agent2 R  B 4 5(NEWLINE)

Comment: possible to have a Live chat if you have spare time thanks

Comment: I have updated the code. please check again. There was some small issue earlier. Tested and updated now. What you want to know.

Comment: i would like to know  as in you code the function will return which element is bigger right say array1[3]  is greter then array2[3]   (say array1[3] == 10,array2[3] == 3) so it will return 10 right . but i want that whole string not only the element .  sorry if i am talking wrong i am just a begginer in  java and not too much grip on libraries and functions.

Comment: This comparison is to define the re-ordering in the array. This is called internally by `Arrays.sort` method. Please check these two links you will understand it. [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88922/discussion-between-nav-and-abhishek-bafna).